# Make a dynamic image follow mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

There is this version of image following mouse:

http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/1/

And I've tried to make it work with a dynamically loaded image like this:

```
var a = new Image();
a.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/This_is_a_demo_blue_dot.png';
a.onload = g;

function g(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $(a).css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work. I need it to work this way since I am going have to draw it on canvas too later on.

I guess the problem is that jQuery can't find the image that way, so how do I make it work?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: The dynamically loaded image does not follow the mouse. try the second code I've shown and you will see that nothing really happens.

Comment: @user1938653 I removed the extra question you edited in earlier. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `id` to the element and append it in the `DOM`

As `position : absolute;` is being applied through `css`, applying `id` over image element is essential.

```js
var a = new Image();
a.id = 'image';
a.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/This_is_a_demo_blue_dot.png';
$('body').append(a);
a.onload = g;

function g() {
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $(a).css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```